# Display a grid of JPanels in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm very new to Java but have some experience with C++. This is a homework assignment so I'm really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

The assignment requires a `JFrame` with `JPanel` objects displaying every card in a deck in a 13x4 grid. The Professor has supplied us with some code to get us started:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //load the card image from the gif file.
    final ImageIcon cardIcon = new ImageIcon("cardImages/tenClubs.gif");

    //create a panel displaying the card image
    JPanel panel = new JPanel()
    {
        //paintComponent is called automatically by the JRE whenever
        //the panel needs to be drawn or redrawn
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            cardIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 20, 20);
        }
    };

    //create & make visible a JFrame to contain the panel
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Title goes here");
    window.add(panel);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I have tried out a few things, but I can't seem to get multiple panels to display. Should I use a `gridLayout()` feature? or just create multiple panels and specify each one's location in the frame?

Again if someone can just point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: *"Should I use a gridLayout() feature?"*  If by that you mean a `GridLayout` then yes.  Personally I'd display the images in a `JLabel` (added to the panel, possibly).

Comment: Thanks for the correction Andrew, this is my first Java program so I am very ignorant at the moment. I will check out your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

For displaying elements at the same size, evenly distributed within the container, then yes, `GridLayout` would be a good choice.

If you need to display the components in the grid at there preferred size (which may be different for each component) then `GridBagLayout` would be a better choice

If the code was supplied by a your professor, then you need to go back and make them fix it.

Firstly, a `JLabel` would be easier and provide better support for what you are trying to achieve...

Secondly, because the `JPanel` doesn't override `getPreferredSize`, most of the layout managers will set the size of the component to 0x0

Answer (score -2):

There is a way to display multiple JPanels in one JFrame. Unlucky you the way is not so easy. Java has many diffrent LayoutManagers.
For your purpose I would recommend GridBagLayout, it is more complex, but definately the thing you need.
Here is a good tutorial, which helped me to understand it:

[GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Hope it is a help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I will definitely check it out.  I would like to note, the professor didn't specifically say we have to use multiple JPanels, he just supplied us with the above code and .gifs for each card, so if there is an easier way to do this please let me know but I am going to get started on GridBagLayout tutorials.

Comment: *"For your purpose I would recommend GridBagLayout.."*  Why GBL rather than `GridLayout` in this case?  AFAIU all the cells need to be the same size, hence `GridLayout`.

Comment: Because the JPanel (which is supposedly supplied by the professor) doesn't override getPreferredSize, GridBagLayout would be a bad choice, because it will want to use this about to make decisions about how to layout its components, making all the panel's 0x0 by default...

Comment: ok, you are right, I just was thinking one step further. Why just showing the cards without any information... So Gridlayout works as well